# How to number rows of a TableView using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to number the rows of a TableView, so that each cell displays its number using Swift.

For example: the first cell displays a 1, the second a 2, and so on...

[image: Example Image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? Are you using a UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Comment: My suggestion is to google something like "ios tableView tutorial", and that should do the job.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this.

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

cell.someLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)." //You have to + 1 ,because cells are zero based.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want a static table, the simplest way is to have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` simply fill the text field with a string representation of `indexPath.row + 1` and have `numberOfRowsInSection` return however many rows there should be.

The more elegant way (in anticipation of doing something meaningful in table views) is to

- build a "model", i.e. an array of strings to be shown in the table view;
- have `numberOfRowsInSection` return the `count` of that model array; and
- have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the label's `text` property to be the appropriate item from your model array.

I suspect, though, that your question is more fundamental, wondering how to use table views in general. For that, I would suggest you google "UITableView Swift tutorial" or something like that, and I'm sure you'll find many relevant examples online.

Comment: This works perfectly. I was making a silly error and did not change the numberOfRowsInSection count to reflect this.

Comment: I have, but since I do not have enough reputation I am not allowed. Unfortunately , I cannot gain access to my previous account where I had upwards of 1000 experience.

Comment: You have insufficient reputation to upvote. But you can still accept answers by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer (and that helps build your reputation, BTW).

Comment: Haha, I don't think he understood. @Rob I'll give some credit to you, +1

Answer (score -1):

Rather than just returning the items in the array, you should also prefix it by returning the index of each cell. Remember that indices start from 0 so don't forget to add one.